# Вычислить сумму элементов матрицы в столбцах

Tags: алгоритм, матрицы, php

Имеется следующий код, заполняющий матрицу рандомными числами и выводящий её элементы:

```
<?php

$sum_col = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $sum_row = 0;
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 7; $j++) {
        $matrix[$i][$j] = rand(-100, 100);
        $sum_row        = $sum_row + $matrix[$i][$j];
        echo $matrix[$i][$j] . ' ';
        if ($j == 7)
            echo $sum_row . '</br>';
    }
}

?>
```

Сумма элементов в строках матрицы вычисляется корректно. Никак не могу додуматься, как посчитать и вывести в последней строке сумму элементов в столбцах.

Comment: ИМХО, логика отсутствует напрочь. Сначала матрица должна быть сгенерирована, а потом уже можно выполнять над ней операции.

Comment: Думал над этим. Потом решил, что для вычисления сумм нужно не так много добавлять кода и решил всё смешать. В итоге сам запутался)). Перепишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен что хороший вариант, но доделать не составит труда :)

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    $sum_row=0;
    for($j=1; $j<=7; $j++)  {
    $matrix[$i][$j]=rand(-100, 100);
    $sum_row=$sum_row+$matrix[$i][$j];
    echo $matrix[$i][$j].' ';
    if ($j==7) echo $sum_row.'</br>';
    }
}
for ($i=1; $i<=7; $i++) {
    $sum_col=0;
    for($j=1; $j<=5; $j++)  {
    $sum_col=$sum_col+$matrix[$j][$i];

    }
    echo $sum_col.' ';
}
?>
```